# Webpack: manually added compilation file dependency should force rebuild

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, laravel-mix

I'm using Webpack 2 (via Laravel Mix) to compile a Javascript asset in different languages, much like Webpack's own [i18n plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/i18n-webpack-plugin). I've built a custom implementation, though, which plays nicely with Mix's helpers. There is one final issue, though, which I cannot wrap my head around, which has to do with the watch process. Here's a summary of what is happening:

- An app.js file has several dependencies which compose the actual logic
- Mix is instructed to create a different file for each language, where each one can have their placeholder strings replaced with actual translations (this will eventually output `en.[hash].js`, `pt.[hash].js`, etc)
- Webpack will process all those dependencies and create a bundled file with all the code
- When Webpack is about to emit the final files, I process the translation placeholders with actual language strings using a JSON file (`en.json`, `pt.json`, etc; incidentally, Laravel's own language JSON files)

The JSON files are not included in the actual `app.js` file, so Webpack ignores them when doing `watch`. I've managed to trigger compilation when I change those JSON files, though, by injecting them as dependencies, in my plugin's `apply` method:

```
compiler.plugin('emit', (compilation, callback) => {
    mix.config.locales.forEach(_.bind(function (locale) {
        const file = path.resolve(this.translationsPath, `${locale}.json`)
        if (!_.includes(compilation.fileDependencies, file)) {
            compilation.fileDependencies.push(file);
        }
    }, this))
    callback()
})
```

The problem is, even though Webpack re-compiles my `app.js` when I change the language JSON files, since they are not really part of the script Webpack will not recognise any changes and will not rebuild the script, so any actual changes in translation don't take effect during watch.

1) Can I tell webpack to force a rebuild when the JSON files change?

An additional limitation I can think of is this: since the final file's hashes are generated before translation, even if I trigger a rebuild the hashes will be exactly the same, so when deploying to production the browser's won't know the translations have been updated and will still serve a cached version of the script. Which leads me to:

2) Is there a way to ask Webpack to regenerate the hash? Or, alternatively, process a compiled file's content before the hash is generated?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using `ejs` partials with `webpack v5.73.0` and `ejs-webpack-loader`.
Changes to the partials (.ejs files) did not cause a rebuild, no live reload. After implementing a custom plugin to add them as dependencies, changes were reflected after disabling cache in my webpack dev config.

```
// Webpack development config
module.exports = {
...
 cache: false
...
}
```

The code that added the templates folder as a dependency

```
module.exports = class WatchPartials {
    apply(compiler) {
      compiler.hooks.afterCompile.tap("Custom watcher", (compilation) => {
        [path.join(<src directory>, '/templates')].forEach((path) =>
          compilation.contextDependencies.add(path)
        );
      });
    }
}
```

Initialized it as you would for a webpack plugin

```
const WatchPartials  = require('./configuration/watchPartials')

plugins: [ 
...
    new WatchPartials(),
...
]
```

In summary, the live reload and recompilation on file edit only worked perfectly after setting `cache: false`.

I don't have a proper explanation as to why at this moment, I hope it helps someone looking to get live reload to work on manually configured dependencies on webpack.